# How to get multiple SQL columns into one column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query **"Select A,B,C,(A+B+C) as Total from Test"** and the result is[image]

How to get the same result in only two columns like

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "unpivot".  My preferred method is `apply`:

```
Select v.name, v.value
from Test t cross apply
     (values ('A', A), ('B', B), ('C', C)) v(name, value);
```

The total is not in your result set, but that can also easily be added in.

Answer (score 1):

You can unpivot using `UNION ALL`. I still prefer Gordon's solution though.

```
SELECT 'A' AS name, A AS [value] FROM Test
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', B FROM Test
UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', C FROM Test
```